# Display value that corresponds to a specific date in python

Tags: python, python-datetime

I just started to play around in python and need some help. Let's assume I have a table that looks like this

| Date | Values | Values_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22/01/01 | 1 | 11 |
| 22/01/02 | 2 | 12 |
| 22/01/03 | 2 | 13 |

I would like to display the number from column Values_2 that corresponds with the latest date. So the answer would be 13.

I've tried:

```
df = pd.to_datetime(['Date'])
df["Date"].max()

#and

df_updated = df[['Date'] == '22/01/03'].groupby('Values_2').mean()
```

But can't figure out how to get the value from Values_2 that corresponds with the most recent date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1/1/2022', '1/2/2022', '1/3/2022'],
                   'value': [1, 2, 2], 
                   'value_2': [11, 12, 13]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df[df["date"]==df["date"].max()]['value_2']
```

Update:
If you want to calculate the mean value,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1/1/2022', '1/2/2022', '1/3/2022', '1/3/2022'],
                   'value': [1, 2, 2, 2], 
                   'value_2': [11, 12, 13, 13]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df[df["date"]==df["date"].max()]['value_2'].mean()
```